# Trying to pass a parameter to a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am trying to pass a parameter to my Product controller, but it's producing an error.

If I have the following code:

```
def index
  @products = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @products }
  end
```

Everything works fine. But when I modify it to:

```
def index
  @products = Product.where('model LIKE ?', '%deluxe%').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10) if params[:selected_term] != nil
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @products }
  end
end
```

I get an error message:

```
The @products variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?
```

In my views/application.html.erb, I have:

```
<% filters = ProductsFilter.all %>
<li><%= link_to "Products", "/product"  %></li>
<% if controller_name == 'products' %>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn">Viewpoint</button>
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <% filters.each do |filter| %>
            <li><%= link_to filter.term, tweet_path(:selected_term => filter.term)  %></li>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

## Solution:

This solved the problem (probably not the most elegant solution):

```
def index
  @products = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  if (params[:selected_term]) != nil
    selected_term = params[:selected_term]
    @products = Product.where('Product_text LIKE ?', "%#{selected_term}%").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
```

Comment: What happens when you run `Product.where('model LIKE ?', '%deluxe%').paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 10)` in your Rails console?

Comment: NameError: uninitialized constant Products, which is what I would expect from the error message I posted in my question. I should actually be using the parameter, instead of banana, but that wouldn't make a difference for the purposes of this question (I think)

Comment: `Products` plural? The model name is likely `Product` and it should definitely not be an uninitialized constant in your console.

Comment: The model name is Product, but if I switch it to Product, I'm still getting an error What I'm trying to do here is pass a parameter to the Product Controller Index Method, and for that I need a conditional statement in the Index method to determine if an argument was passed

Comment: What error do you get if you switch it to Product?

Comment: NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object